# I have two layout in laravel5. If session exist than extends layout one else extends layout two . Is it possible?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two layouts in laravel5. If session exist than extends layout one else extends layout two . Is it possible ? Tried lot scenarios yet not found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

You can use a variable to solve your issue like this:

```
@php
if(auth()->user()) {    {{-- Here you can also use any session variable --}}
        $layout = 'layouts.one';
} else {
        $layout = 'layouts.two';
}
@endphp

@extends($layout)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is possible.
You can do it with a simple if-condition inside your blade files.

```
@if(Session::has('aSessionVarHere')) 
 @extends('layouts.master.session')
@else
 @extends('layouts.master.no-session')
@endif
```

For the validation the `Session` facade is used as written above.